# Realm retains a deleted object

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I had 2 fragments **A** and **B**, in fragment **B** I delete an object using transaction then I execut   `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` to return to the fragment **A**, after deleting the object I debug and I found that the object is correctly deleted, but when I return to fragment **A** I found it, it's weird !

this is my code in my fragment **A**

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                                        Infraction infraction = realm.where(Infraction.class).equalTo("id",id_new_inf).findFirst();
                                        if(infraction != null)
                                            infraction.deleteFromRealm();
                                    }
                            });
  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

So why is the object not deleted?

in Fragment A, I haven't something special, it's just a request in **onCreateView**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_infractions, container, false);
infractions = realm.where(Infraction.class).findAll();
}
```

Comment: also post the code of fragment A. because it also depends on how your manipulate data in fragment A

Comment: Are you reloading elements in fragment A?

Comment: please read https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications and https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/

Comment: @beeender so if I understand correctly, I must use something like this, right ?

`realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @ Override
        public void onChange(Realm realm) {
            // ... do something with the updates (UI, etc.) ...
        }};
      realm.addChangeListener(realmListener);`

Comment: could you see now ? I'm really blocked now

Comment: yes, that you need to register a listener to do UI refresh. And you need to keep a strong ref to the listener as long as you want the UI to get refreshed.

Comment: Your deletion is asynchronous, so there is no guarantee that navigating back happens AFTER the UI thread Realm instance is updated after the write. So you should use notifications.

Comment: Do you have a small example for notification ? cause I really don't know how or where to use it, thank's

Comment: You could just move the pop Backstack into Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess callback and you wouldn't be having this problem

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync((r) ->
                    Infraction infraction = r.where(Infraction.class).equalTo("id",id_new_inf).findFirst();
                    if(infraction != null)
                          infraction.deleteFromRealm();
                    }
             }, () -> { // on Success 
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .popBackStack();
             });
```